# Anyone know where I can buy this derailleur hanger?

Tags: derailleur-hanger

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know where I can buy a spare part of this dropout? It’s from my commute bike, but not having a brand… Thanks!

Comment: Specifying the bike that it came from would help greatly

Answer (score 6):

That's a very common design. Here are some links that appear to be compatible.

- https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/1-fastener-derailleur-hangers/derailleur-hanger-25.html
- https://derailleurhanger.com/product/derailleur-hanger-25/
- https://www.rearmechhanger.com/product/rear-gear-mech-derailleur-hanger-cc1020/
- https://www.jbi.bike/site/product_details.php?part_number=250036

Answer (score 5):

There are various third party derailleur hanger suppliers online (for example https://derailleurhangerstore.co.uk/ - I doubt that's much use to you, but you haven't said where you are).  Many of them list the parts by the bike make and model.  IF there's any information on the hanger itself, it's not generally very useful. If you don't even know the make/model of your bike, you'll have to look for a visual match, and try to get some information on the threads as well.  Some (especially cheap) bikes are sold under several names

Answer (score 5):

This is Halfords 'Gear Hanger A' which fits many types of bike, but especially the Carrera brand. You can get it here (this is my website): https://fixmymechhanger.co.uk/product/halfords-carrera-boardman-voodoo-rear-derailleur-mech-hanger-dropout-1/

Comment: Thank you for the edit - much appreciated.  Curiously, your item is cheaper than Halford's item, suggesting they only want to sell whole items, not repair-parts.